# Internet wall box damaged, wet

Tags: ethernet, internet, electronics

Water spilled on the box on the wall that my Ethernet ports are in (internet gateway?). Now the internet doesn't work. I tried drying it as much as possible but it's connected to the wall so that's not super easy. I will call ASAP once my internet provider opens tomorrow but was wondering if there's anything I can do in the meantime.

[image]

Comment: Looks like a fiber gateway. If you got it wet, it’s probably dead. Call AT&T.

Comment: unplug it from power

Comment: You could try putting a fan on it.

Comment: Usually water and electronics do not mix well, especially if the power is on.  Replacement is usually the only hope.  Unplug it and hope damage did not go past the that box to anything that was plugged/wired to it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't about home improvement, but general electronics repair.

Answer (score 2):

Unplug it.

Wait for AT&T to come check it out.

There's not much more you can do. It's clearly labeled that it's their property, and they probably won't be particularly happy if you mess with it further. They may charge you (more) for the visit if they determine that you've done anything more than that.